# Without Manual intervention need to get complete telnet output

Tags: linux, shell, tcp, telnet

I need to get the exact telnet output without any manual intervention

```
-bash-4.2# echo exit | telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1…
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
Connection closed by foreign host.

-bash-4.2# telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1…
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
```

Here when use `telnet localhost 22` "SSH-2 OpenSSH_7.4" is showing , but in `echo exit | telnet localhost 22` it’s not showing

Output :

```
bash-4.2# echo exit | telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1…
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
Connection closed by foreign host.
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
-bash-4.2#
```

I have tried the below comments also 
"Connection closed."

```
-bash-4.2# cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
^C
-bash-4.2# echo exit | cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4  (I want to execute and close automatically)
```

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you are trying to accomplish?  For example, if you simply need to capture the output and script the input, you might consider Netcat.  If that's not your goal, please try to explain it better.

Comment: Got answer dude, I want to capture the exact output, Thanks for your time

Comment: When you have an answer you like, select the one that works best for you and `accept` that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try;

```
read a < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
echo "Output is $a"
```

The $a variable will contain the text "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4".

Answer (score 0):

Telnet sill start reading the input after some initial steps (connecting?).
You must give telnet some time to start before you end your input.

```
(sleep 1 ; echo quit) | telnet localhost 22
```

The `echo` is not needed:

```
sleep 1 |telnet localhost 22
```

Avoid some garbage in the output

```
sleep 1 |netcat localhost 22
```

Comment: Simply superb, Thank you so much dude :)